# Applescript "Can’t make "Saturday, April 1, 2023 at 16:05:41" into type date."

Tags: string, datetime, applescript

Believe it or not, I've googled all over for this simple thing and can't find it anywhere. I have a string which has the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format, but I generated it from a shell script, so it can be anything.
Applescript however seems to only accept a very specific string format which I can't guess and can't find documentation for.  I've tried every format I can think of.   Shockingly I can't even get this code to work, which takes Applescript's own format and just feeds it back:

```
set theDate to (current date) as string
set tDate to theDate as date
```

Whereupon applescript issues the error "Can’t make "Saturday, April 1, 2023 at 14:49:59" into type date."
How is this even possible?  Can anyone please tell me the magic format?
I know it might depend on my system settings, but so how do I find what my settings are right now and give the script the right string?
Thanks!

If I look in the Applescript dictionary, it provides a non-descriptive answer.  Just says "In constructing a date, you may use any string value that can be interpreted as a date, a time, or a date-time."  Examples please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A simple search for `[applescript] date` will generate several results that have solutions for this question. I think this question should be closed as a duplicate but at least it should show some research beyond looking at the dictionary which incidentally, does offer the solution, albeit tersely: `date theDate` — you're not coercing (since you've already coerced the date to text, as noted in the dictionary).

Comment: Alternatives… `date "2022-1-31"` (or whatever your date format in System Preferences is)  or `date "march 31, 2022"` or even (with coercion) `set xy to {y:2021, m:11, d:25}`, `date "8:30" of date ((y of xy & "-" & m of xy & "-" & d of xy) as text)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related topics has already been chewed and chewed many times. I'll just repeat what should work specifically for the case "YYYY-MM-DD".

You have the wrong question here. The point is that you need to **put the order of "YYYY-MM-DD" in accordance with the order in your locale**. In different locales, the order of Year, Month, Day is different and will often not be "YYYY-MM-DD".

AppleScript can't guess the right order just by coercion, automatically. This does not work. Moreover, this was not to be expected. How, for example, could AppleScript discern what is a day and what is a month in a pair ("11", "05")? No way.

Therefore, you have to **specify the order explicitly by writing the correct transform** (better as handler).

```
myShellStringDateToAppleScriptDate("2024-11-05") -- string's order is not localized: YYYY-MM-DD

on myShellStringDateToAppleScriptDate(shellDate)
    set AppleScriptDate to (current date) -- creates new date object with localized order
    tell AppleScriptDate -- put the order of "YYYY-MM-DD" in accordance with the order in your locale
        set year to text 1 thru 4 of shellDate
        set its month to text 6 thru 7 of shellDate
        set day to text 9 thru 10 of shellDate
    end tell
    return AppleScriptDate
end myShellStringDateToAppleScriptDate
```

**Note**:

Shells provide a way for passing a date with an indication of the localization order. There is a so-called **ISOT string** for this. Correct transmission of the date between remote users via shells requires exactly the ISOT format. Given an ISOT string, you can convert it to an AppleScript date using AsObjC code:

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set isotDate to "2020-05-07T06:05:34Z" -- ISOT string returned from shell
set formatter to current application's NSISO8601DateFormatter's new()
set theAppleScriptDate to (formatter's dateFromString:isotDate) as date
set theAppleScriptDate to theAppleScriptDate - (time to GMT)
```

Finally, **AsObjC** can also be used by **explicitly specifying the shell string format**:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set todaysDate to do shell script "date '+%Y-%m-%d'" --> "2023-04-02"

set df to current application's NSDateFormatter's new()
df's setDateFormat:"y-M-d" -- related "YYYY-MM-DD" format
set theDate to (df's dateFromString:todaysDate) as date
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **coerce** the string to `date`, but you can create a date from a string this way

```
set theDate to (current date) as string
set tDate to date theDate
```